# Preg_replace - Clickable url with long url

Tags: php, regex

I uses a PHP script with preg_replace to make an clickable URL.

```
        function link_replace($bericht) {
            $bericht = preg_replace("#(^|[ \n\r\t])((http(s?)://)(www\.)?([a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)+)(/[^/ \n\r]*)*)#","\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $bericht);
            $bericht = preg_replace("#(^|[ \n\r\t])((ftp://)(www\.)?([a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)+)(/[^/ \n\r]*)*)#","\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $bericht);
            $bericht = preg_replace("#([a-z_-][a-z0-9\._-]*@[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)+)#","<a href=\"mailto:\\1\">\\1</a>", $bericht);
            $bericht = preg_replace("#(^|[ \n\r\t])(www\.([a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)+)(/([^/ \n\r]*[^/ \n\r\.])*)?)#","\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $bericht);
            $bericht = preg_replace("#(^|[ \n\r\t])(ftp\.([a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)+)(/[^/ \n\r]*)*)#","\\1<a href=\"ftp://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $bericht);
            $bericht = nl2br($bericht);
            return $bericht;
        }
```

The above code works fine, except when there is a longer url, a longer path with more then 1 backslah.

Example:

[www.xxx.com/xxx/xxx](http://www.xxx.com/xxx/xxx) results in clickable link: [www.xxx.com/xxx](http://www.xxx.com/xxx)

The last characters behind the last backslash are not part of the clickable URL. What can I change tot the regex code to make it work?

Comment: So in the end result, all urls should have only a single forward slash like `www.xxx.com/xxx` ?

Comment: No thats not what I mean. When I have in the tekst the follow url: www.test.com/sub1/sub2

The link must be: <a href="www.test.com/sub1/sub2">www.test.com/sub1/sub2</a> 

The problem is that the result is: <a href="www.test.com/sub1">www.test.com/sub1</a> /sub2

Comment: So it should be like this? https://3v4l.org/0ON2N

Comment: The first url must be: <a href="www.example.com/xxx/xxx" target="_blank">www.example.com/xxx/xxx</a> 

The second sub disapears

Comment: Because `xxx` is a "naughty" site, Stack Overflow recommends that you use `www.example.com` when obfuscating a url is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

There is a trailing text after the link because it is not matched, and you use a replacement so that text will be there after the replacement.

The example link if matched by the fourth part, where you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/qysM1c/1) that the unmatched part is still present after the replacement.

You might shorten the pattern a bit to use 2 capturing groups instead to keep it working with the rest of the patterns as you use group 1 and group 2 in the replacement.

The last part of the pattern could be repeated 0+ times to keep all the parts with the forward slashes

You could also shorten this part `[ \n\r\t]` to `\s`

```
(^|\s)(www\.[a-z0-9_-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9_-]+)+(?:/[^/\s.]+)*)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gGGwdL/1) and a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/hkhJS)